# JavaScript assign function to object property

Tags: javascript, class, oop, methods

I was looking at the source code of a JavaScript library and encountered something like this in a class definition:

```
var MyClass = function() {
    function doSomething() {
        // function definition
    }

    this.doSomething = function() {
        doSomething();
    };
}
```

So, my question is: is there any reason someone would do this instead of simply assigning the function to the object method like this:

```
this.doSomething = doSomething;
```

Comment: [design to protect members](http://philipwalton.com/articles/implementing-private-and-protected-members-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on exactly what `doSomething` is actually doing.  There is a difference in how `this` will be bound within the function.  If you call it as per your example, it won't have `this` bound to the object, whereas if you call it with it assigned directly to a property, then `this` will be bound to the instance:

```js
var MyClass = function() {
  this.n = "Bob";
  function doSomething() {
    console.log(this.n);
  }

  this.doSomething = function() {
    doSomething();
  };
  this.doSomethingDirect = doSomething;
}

var x = new MyClass();

x.doSomething();        //undefined
x.doSomethingDirect();  //"Bob"
```